# To Experts: What's The Difference In This Code?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, c#-3.0, generics

I ask this because I got an error "ArgumentOutOfRange" using the generic form.

```
  List<WaitHandle> arraywaithandles = new List<WaitHandle>(4);
```

or...

```
    WaitHandle[] A = new WaitHandle[4]
```

This works:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            A[i] = (arrayresultados[i].AsyncWaitHandle);
        }
```

This does not work:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            arraywaithandles[i] = (arrayresultados[i].AsyncWaitHandle);
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
new List<WaitHandle>(4);
```

[creates a `List` object that has an **initial capacity** of 4 `WaitHandles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx). What that means is that the `List` after the above line will hold zero `WaitHandles`, but has at least enough memory to receive 4 `WaitHandles` without having to perform an extra memory allocation later.

This way, if you know you will need to insert 200 `WaitHandles` but don't actually have them right now, you can have the `List` object allocate enough memory for 200 `WaitHandles` in one go instead of having to reallocate as you add `WaitHandles`.

That's why your first `for` loop threw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception because you tried to access non-existing `WaitHandles` in `arraywaithandles`. If you need to add `WaitHandles` to the `List`, then you would use the aptly named [`List<T>::Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx).

This, on the other hand:

```
new WaitHandle[4];
```

creates an array of 4 `WaitHandles` that will be in existence by the time the above line finishes.

Comment: So let's change the question: Is there a way to express generic form as follows:

WaitHandle[] A = new WaitHandle[4];

I ask this, because I could only see the capacity property, the property count is read-only . In this way, I do not want to separate memory for N elements, I want to create a collection that will have N elements. Thanks.

Comment: @ludicode: If you have another question, it's best to ask it as another question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ludicode: if you know you want 4 WaitHandles, no more, no less, then just stick with the array. Use the List if you want a collection of WaitHandles where you can add and remove items.

Answer (score 2):

You want to try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    arraywaithandles.Add(arrayresultados[i].AsyncWaitHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<WaitHandle> arraywaithandles = 
    Enumerable.Repeat<WaitHandle>(null, 4).ToList();
```